# upload doesn't finish

Tags: upload

the file upload always does not finish and it shows no error alert. Also in the logs there is no error.

I only find an error in the browser debugger on actions/assets/uploadFile . Maybe the error helps:

```
n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:4n.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:4$.widget._onSend.send @ jquery.fileupload.js?d=1436808910:880(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2n.Callbacks.j @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2n.Callbacks.k.add @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2n.extend.each @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2n.extend.Deferred @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2n.extend.Deferred.d.then @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2$.widget._onSend @ jquery.fileupload.js?d=1436808910:924(anonymous function) @ jquery.ui.widget.js?d=1436808910:105$.widget._addConvenienceMethods.data.submit @ jquery.fileupload.js?d=1436808910:648(anonymous function) @ craft.js:13685n.extend.proxy.n.isFunction.f @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2n.Callbacks.j @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2n.Callbacks.k.add @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2Craft.Uploader.Garnish.Base.extend.onFileAdd @ craft.js:13653n.extend.proxy.n.isFunction.f @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2n.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:3n.event.add.r.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:3n.event.trigger @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:3(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:3n.extend.each @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2n.fn.n.each @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2n.fn.extend.trigger @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:3$.Widget._trigger @ jquery.ui.widget.js?d=1436808910:487(anonymous function) @ jquery.fileupload.js?d=1436808910:1008n.extend.each @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2$.widget._onAdd @ jquery.fileupload.js?d=1436808910:1001(anonymous function) @ jquery.ui.widget.js?d=1436808910:105(anonymous function) @ jquery.fileupload.js?d=1436808910:1200n.Callbacks.j @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2n.Callbacks.k.add @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2n.extend.Deferred.d.always @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:2$.widget._onChange @ jquery.fileupload.js?d=1436808910:1190(anonymous function) @ jquery.ui.widget.js?d=1436808910:105handlerProxy @ jquery.ui.widget.js?d=1436808910:406n.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:3n.event.add.r.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js?d=1436808909:3
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You sure there's no error in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`?  Or in your browser's console tab?

Comment: Have you tried different file **types**? Different file **sizes**? There have been a variety of similar questions here on Stack Exchange... knowing if the file type or file size is part of the issue will be helpful in finding an answer for you.

Comment: This just started happening to me on a site... uploads were working perfectly before this morning. Help!

Comment: Never mind my issue is an Imagick issue on Webfaction.

Comment: now i have an error and it seems my problem is Imagick too:
'error] [exception.Imagine\Exception\RuntimeException] exception 'ImagickException' with message 'NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `/var/www/virtual/conwave/html/service/cgk/craft/storage/runtime/temp/assets55ccc39412a3d4.11352011.jpg' @ constitute.c/ReadImage/503' in /var/www/virtual/conwave/html/service/cgk/craft/app/vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Imagick/Imagine.php:52'

Comment: can someone help me?